# Breakpoints from regular bootstrap(not react-bootstrap) doesnt work in my react app

Tags: reactjs, jsx, bootstrap-5

I have this jsx

```
<div
   className="row"
>
              {data!== undefined && data.length !== 0 ? (
                data.map((el) => (
                  <div className="col col-lg-2 col-md-6 g-3" key={el._id}>
                    <div className="card">
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <p className="card-text fw-bold fs-5">{el.name}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))
              ) : (
                <p>no data</p>
              )}
            </div>
```

[image: cards wont move]

Tried to resize my browser window and the cards didnt move, you can see the image. Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works. I guess you didn't include Bootstrap correctly in your React project.

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-acx6ws?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter).

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "stackblitz-starters-acx6ws",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  }
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button className="btn btn-success">Success</button>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col col-lg-2 col-md-6 g-3">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <p className="card-text fw-bold fs-5">Card</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col col-lg-2 col-md-6 g-3">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <p className="card-text fw-bold fs-5">Card</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col col-lg-2 col-md-6 g-3">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <p className="card-text fw-bold fs-5">Card</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: these were mine: import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"; then I tried yours and still cards wont move

Comment: It is so weird. Does the bootstrap version affect this?

Comment: Can you please create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) snippet? I need to be able to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, it's just pure guessing.

Comment: The cards are responsive in stackblitz. I think something is wrong with my react app but I dont know what is causing it. This the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6ygr8q?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: The Stackblitz snippet you've provided works as expected, right? Try to add `<button class="btn btn-success">Lorem ipsum</div>` somewhere in your project. Does the green button get rendered?

Comment: Yes it does. Why?

Comment: It means that Bootstrap CSS works in general. Can you make a screenshot of the rendered HTML like [this](https://imgur.com/Hh7qDMG)?

Comment: Update: I uninstalled the bootstrap and im using the cdn links from bootstrap and works well. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note, here is a suggestive cleaner code:

```
{ data.length && ( 
    data.map((el) => (
        <div className="col col-lg-2 col-md-6 g-3" key={el._id}>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                   <p className="card-text fw-bold fs-5">{el.name}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
)}
```

If the array is empty or undefined, it will always turn false so there's no need to add the other conditions so this should work the same.

Comment: react version is 18.2.0 and i just updated the bootstrap to the newest version. These the index and app js https://gist.github.com/regularcoder99/c199e731235a2f0c87afd7f7d1deb0ba

Comment: Those versions should be compatible I read that you've got a CDN and is all working!